# Javascript : accurate CSS TranslateX ( position ) taking Transform Scale into account

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, coffeescript

I'm scaling a `div.parent` by n% using `transform : scale( 0.25 )`. The width of `div.parent` is quite large and exceeds the viewport bounds. This container `div` has n children, each with a relative offset position, which I'm getting via `jQuery` like ( approximation )

```
parent  = $ '.parent'
child   = $ '.child'
posLeft = child.position().left
```

I'm then moving the `div.parent` container using the value `posLeft`.

```
 parent.css
    transform : "translate3d( #{posLeft}px, 0, 0 )"
```

I would like to expand the `function` that handles the above animation by allowing it to continue to *move* `div.parent` accurately ( as related to the child items `posLeft` ) when it's scaled down. Here's an image to help illuminate the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be really simple — after eliminating a few bugs in my code. For anyone else who is interested in doing something similar, I'll post an approximation of the code below ( which uses `TweenMax` to handle the transitions )

```
 _state = 
     scale : 1

 state: ( state, value )-> 
     if value is undefined
         return _state[state] 
     else 
         _state[state] = value 

 calculateDistance( distance, scale )->
     newDistance = distance * scale
     return newDistance 


 scaleDown = ( amount )->
     if amount > 1 then amount = 1

     props =
         x                   : 0 
         scale               : amount 
         transformOrigin     : 'center left'
         onComplete          : Done 

         TweenMax.to container, 0.4, props 

  Done =->
      num = this.vars.css.scale 

      state( 'scale', num )
```

and how to use `calculateDistance()`

```
location =  calculateDistance( move.destination.attr( 'data-location' ), state('scale' ) )
```

This enables me to use 1 method for both the scaled and full versions of any transitions.